# Controller Scaffolding Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to scaffold a controller for the following model for EF but I'm receiving:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Project.Models.ItemModel'.
>
> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: entitySet'

Is it trying to retrieve something from somewhere but cant?

**ItemModel**

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public class ItemPicture
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("ItemModel")]
        public virtual int ItemID {get;set;}

        public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }

        public virtual ItemModel ItemModel { get; set; }
    }


    [Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="{0} is required.")]
    [Display(Name ="Item Name")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Item Description")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string ItemDesc { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Item Price")]
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual ItemPicture Picture { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Enable Front Feature")]
    public bool FrontFeature { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How your dbContext look likes?

Comment: @T.Rahgooy http://pastebin.com/H40Ur0Ld

Comment: Did you build your project before scaffolding?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin yes but error still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried it myself... don't think you should store HttpPostedFileBase as a property of your model, well at least not map it via EntityFramework and let it automatically scaffold. If you think about it - what database fields do you think this property type would map to?

If you want to actually store the binary data in your database, use the following:

```
public byte[] File { get; set; }
```